# Scikit-learn RandomizedLasso and RandomizedLogisticRegression Deprecated

Tags: scikit-learn

I noticed that `linear_model.RandomizedLasso` and `linear_model.RandomizedLogisticRegression` which implement stability selection for lasso regression have been deprecated. Does anyone know why? Is stability selection not a sound method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scikit-learn is developed as open-source and with high standards. This means, that most decisions are transparent.

So you can check out [their repo @ github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) and with some search you will find:

- [the discussion which lead to deprecation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8995)
- [a newer discussion discussing re-adding it](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9657)

  - Citation: *The users are revolting at #8995 :)*