# ImportError: cannot import name 'RandomizedLasso' from 'sklearn.linear_model'

Tags: scikit-learn

ImportError: cannot import name 'RandomizedLasso' from 'sklearn.linear_model' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model_*init*_.py)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scikit-learn RandomizedLasso and RandomizedLogisticRegression Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082474/scikit-learn-randomizedlasso-and-randomizedlogisticregression-deprecated)

Comment: In other words, it’s been removed.